# Why we are storing variable data using %d instead of %p as scanf takes it as a pointer?

Tags: c

I got complete idea that I have to use a `%p` for find address of a variable (`&VAR`) a pointer,
but storing a value we use `scanf("%d", &a)` but not `scanf("%p", &a)` — but why?

I have read some book that they said that `printf("%d", &a)` wrong, instead `printf("%p", &a)`.
According to above statement, I got some confusion with `scanf` function as my first statement.
Any reason for it?

Comment: You use `%p` to print pointers as long as you don't mind that the format is platform specific.  If you do mind, then you use the type `uintptr_t` (from `<stdint.h>`) and the conversion specifiers such as `PRIXPTR` or `PRIxPTR` or `PRIuPTR` from `<inttypes.h>`.  You don't normally use `scanf()` to read a pointer; pointers written to disk are seldom valid in the current program, so there is seldom a reason to do so.  If you must do so, then `%d` is almost invariably wrong — it works by coincidence if `sizeof(int) == sizeof(int *)`, which is true on 32-bit systems but not on most 64-bit systems.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that `printf` only cares about a value; it doesn't care where it comes from. So, to print an integer, you just use `printf("%d", a)`. You can also use a constant integer, as in `printf("%d", 42)`.

However, since `scanf` reads an integer and stores it away, it needs to know where to store it to. Thus, you must pass the *address* of a variable, which `scanf` will store the integer into.

Answer (score 0):

The format directives & specifiers for `scanf()` and `printf()` have similarities, but their specifications are independent.  Expecting the functionality of one and applying it to the other has limitations.

Example `"%d"` and `"%i"` perform exactly the same for `printf()`, but slightly different for `scanf()`.

```
// %d needs a corresponding address of an int.
// By providing an address, scanf() knows where to store the int it scans.
int i;
scanf("%d", &i);  

// %d needs a corresponding int.
// By providing an int, printf() knows what int to print.
int j;
printf("%d", j);
```